# ui-scroll listview extending through screen cutting right border off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an application using html and javascript. I have a ui-scrolllistview on one page and I have it populating ok. But if a word is too big for the listview it just extends the width of it so it goes out of the screen.

Is there a way to set the length of a word or word wrap words within the ui-scrolllistview so that it does not cut off the right border of the ui-scrolllistview?

Thanks

EDIT

here is my code that is creating the page with the ui-scrolllist

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="f" id="choose-building">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1><img src="images/building.png" height="80px"></h1>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right topzero">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back"  data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <a id="applyFilter" data-role="button" data-inline="true" onClick="pickedBuildings();">Chosen Buildings</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-scroll="Y" class="ui-scrolllistview" >
        <form>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">          

            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="CatagoryChooseBuilding" >
            </fieldset>

        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="f" data-position="inline" data-id="main-footer"  data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div data-role="navbar" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="myapp-home" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page-map" data-role="button" data-icon="myapp-building-a" >Buildings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#more" data-role="button" data-icon="myapp-more" >More</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->  
</div>
```

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer and vote it up if it has proved useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it sounds like you're looking for `text-overflow` and `white-space` and possibly `overflow`.

You can use these different CSS properties to stop the text at whatever dimensions you would care to **after** setting up your `margins` and `padding`.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

**Edit**: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/urSSJ/)

You can adjust the margin properties until you have scooted your text as far away from the scrollbars as you would like.

**Edit**: If you want to allow word wrapping where the Framework (jQuery mobile according to your tags) truncates it for you, on the inner-most element that contains your text, specify `overflow: visible;` and `white-space:normal;`

If you are not seeing the behavior change as you are expecting and wanting it to, then view the page through a Developer Tools window. These are built into Chrome and IE and you can use Firebug for Firefox. These allow you to test stylesheet changes 'on the fly' which sounds like what you'll need to get the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: so these are put added to the style="padding:0..." is it?

Comment: You can specify these styles in-line if you prefer but a generally more accepted approach is to put the CSS in a separate `.css` file that you include. My example shows what that would approximately look like (except jsfiddle.net 'includes' it for you)

Comment: all it seems to be doing is making the actual ui-scroll list width less and not affecting the text at all

Comment: @HipHipArray, it would be easier to help you diagnose the situation if you could provide a link or example at what you are seeing. You'll need to attach the styling onto the proper element. For example, if you have a `span` inside of an `li` inside of a `ul` then if you want the text inside the `span` to be shortened then you'll need to apply the styling on the `span`.

Comment: the problem is that the ui-scrolllist is setting to the size of the text and not the size of the screen, i must find out how to set it to the size of the screen

Comment: @HipHipArray, I believe you're looking for something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/urSSJ/8/). Be sure to vote up if you have found this helpful.